# php image update query, how to update the query

Tags: php, mysql, image

Exampe list view:

[image: image 1]

Example of edit view:

[image: image 2]

```php
 $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
     $sql = "INSERT INTO imgexam
                        (image, name)
                        VALUES
                        ('{$imgData}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}');";
```

How to change the query, so it will update the current image instead of inserting a new one?

Comment: its getting inserted properly but its jus not getting updated. can anyone give me the update query for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: The title should be more clear and the question should be clearly asked in the body. What are you updating it to? What have you tried? What errors or unexpected behavior are you getting?

Comment: i stored the image in the databse by this update query. its getting stored perfectly and while i display it in a table i am able to view the image. now i want to update the image like i want to change another image instead of this image for a particular Id what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

So what you have to do to update it to the new image is the following steps:

- Remove old image Upload
- new image Update the row in the database to
- the name of the new image

How to remove old image using PHP:

```
unlink('directory/images/'.$image);
```

You might need to do a selection from the database to get the right image name.

How to upload new image using PHP:
[Read this page](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for more informations on uploading files

Then after uploading the new image, you need to change the row in the database.

How to change the row in the database

```
$sql = "UPDATE FROM `table` SET `imagename` = '$newimagename' WHERE `imagename` = $oldimagename";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Thats is the steps you need. Ask if you have problems.

Comment: why is this unlink for? actually i havent stored the images in any of the folder. i have jus stored it directly in tha database what should i do now?

Comment: We need to remove  file from storage,Okay then no need to do this step

Comment: i have used blob data type to store it in database

Comment: Yes,You can see that in my answer.Can you forward screen shot of you error if any

Comment: $query = "UPDATE mytable SET blobthing = '" .
mysql_escape_string($varblobthing) .
"' WHERE id=2";

Comment: bro i have added the image. The first image is the one which shows the image that i retrived from the database and displayed it in a table. when i click edit option there it will redirect me to the edit page where the page will be like my second image. The thing is when i select some other picture and click on update the old picture must be replaced with new one. For that only i am asking update query

Comment: bro i am add it below

Comment: $query = "UPDATE mytable SET blobthing = '" .mysql_escape_string($varblobthing) .
"' WHERE id=2";

Comment: what does this blobthing mean

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query you're looking for to update a record would be similar to this:

```
UPDATE imgexam SET image = ? WHERE name = ?;
```

If you have duplicate names, you'll want to retrieve the ID for the record and use that in the `WHERE` clause. You can get the ID with a method like [PDO::lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) or by querying for it.

What you may also be looking for is sometimes called an `UPSERT` operation. This means I want to `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. MySQL provides an [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) clause. Let's assume `ID` is your primary key for this table.

Change your query to read

```
INSERT INTO 
    imgexam (id, image, name) 
VALUES (1, '{$imageData}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    image = '{$imageData}';
```

Comment: image=and name= what should i fill in it that is my question

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Your parameters (designated by `?`) should be the values you think appropriate. The first `?` should be the new image you wish to store and the second `?` should be the name you want to have a new image.  I can't tell you what these would be with the small snippet you sent me. Also realize this is to change an **existing** record. If you want to simply add a new record, you would use the same query you are now.

Comment: How do i add update query for this?i want to replace the id1 with another image to the image that is already stored in the database
how will be the update query for it?

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=
"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
<input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Comment: $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO imgexam
                    (image, name)
                    VALUES
                    ('{$imgData}', '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}');";

Comment: This is getting a bit too specific for SO. Also, the information you added to comments should probably be edited into the question. That being said to do this in a single statement you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause.

Comment: i need to try i have been busy with another work. going to do this again on monday

Answer (score 0):

Update query for BLOB things:
**mysql_escape_string()** just treats the string as raw bytes, and adds escaping where it believes it's appropriate.

```
$query = "UPDATE mytable SET blobthing = '" .mysql_escape_string($varblobthing) .
"' WHERE id=2";
```

Comment: How do i send screenshot

Comment: Edit your question and post image

Comment: Just check that  images